# How to run Dataflow pipline from a GAE java code instead of Maven?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a Google Cloud DataFlow pipline which i can run it from command line using the following command:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.dataflow.myApp -Dexec.args="--streaming --stagingLocation=gs://gcp-myApp-staging --project=myProject"
```

I need to schedule this process using Cron and i need to run the pipline from a GAE java code. How can I run my pipline code via java instead of using maven?

Answer (score 1):

These two posts explain how to run Dataflow pipelines from GAE and trigger them via Cron:

1) [How to do data processing and analytics from Google App Engine with Google Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/05/how-to-do-data-processing-and-analytics-from-google-app-engine-with-google-cloud-dataflow) by Amy Unruh

2) [Scheduling Dataflow pipelines using App Engine Cron Service or Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions) by  Mete Atamel.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the post [Configuring PipelineOptions for Execution on the Cloud Dataflow Service](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params#CloudExecution)

Comment: I don't think this documentation page specifically addresses the issues of starting a Dataflow pipeline from GAE.